# Fresh Magento 2.3 installation with error: "Area code "version[set of numbers]" does not exist"

Tags: magento2.3

I installed Magento 2.3 with apache, nginx etc.
The frontend and backend both load with multiple CSS and 404 errors.
When I open each error by rightclicking and 'opening with new tab', the same error appears for each error:

```
Area code "version1608495748" does not exist

#0 E:\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\State.php(56): Magento\Framework\App\State->checkAreaCode('version16084957...')
#1 E:\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\State->setAreaCode('version16084957...')
#2 E:\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->___callParent('setAreaCode', Array)
#3 E:\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('version16084957...')
#4 E:\domains\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->___callPlugins('setAreaCode', Array, Array)
#5 E:\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\StaticResource.php(129): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->setAreaCode('version16084957...')
#6 E:\domains\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#7 E:\domains\magento\pub\static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#8 {main}
```

I researched this issue and found no mention of this specific error.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.